# Statsmodel IRF not showing graph

Tags: statsmodels, var

I am trying to plot a graph of IRF for my VAR model. Creating the model went smoothly and now I am interested in IRF figures. However, when I append mymodel firstly into `irf = results.irf(10)` and then into `irf.plot(orth=False)`, I don't get graphs but `<Figure 1000x1000 with 16 axes>`.
Doesn't it require to be inserted into some sort matplotlib plot?

I followed this tutorial: https://www.statsmodels.org/0.6.1/vector_ar.html

I tried searching problems with IRF and found only problems with the graph itself but not the generation of it.